# JQuery Ajax returns status 0 in Google Chrome, works fine with other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am using jQuery ajax, and it worked very well until I tried the site in Google Chrome.
I am directed to the success handler. However, when I printed the status of the XMLHttpRequest, I got a 0. The responseText is empty as well. This only happens in Google Chrome. I tried the same code on Safari, Firefox, and Opera, they are worked correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Curiously I also ran into this several times, especially on the local machine. Some AJAX calls in Chrome just fail, sporadically. On a remote machine it all works fine

Answer (score 0):

It works in Chrome under windows, but not mac. Maybe a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is happening for you only on you local machine (and not on a remote server), maybe this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982176/470749